# Angular Realizar una relación Many-To-One

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot

Estoy intentando hacer una Many-To-One en Angular, basando en las clases Java en Spring Boot. Aquí están los ejemplos:

**User.class**

```
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(name = "userId")
    private String userId;

    @JoinColumn(name = "accountId", referencedColumnName = "accountId", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    private Account account;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
...
}
```

**Account.class**

```
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Size(max = 36)
    @Column(name = "accountId")
    private String accountId;

    @Column(name = "accountName")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name = "company")
    private String company;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "dicomId")
    private String dicomId;

    @Column(name = "enabled")
    @ColumnDefault(value = "1")
    private Integer enabled;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "account",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
                orphanRemoval = true)
    Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
...
}
```

He seguido este tutorial: https://www.techgeeknext.com/spring/angular-spring-boot-jwt-authentication

Por el momento he podido implementar esto:

**HttpClientService.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

export class Account {
  constructor(
    public accountId: string,
    public accountName: string,
    public company: string,
    public address: string,
    public emailAddress: string,
    public dicomId: string,
    public enabled: number
  ) {}
}

export class User {
  constructor(
    public userId: string,
    public account: Account,
    public userName: string,
    public emailAddress: string,
    public password: string,
    public enabled: number,
    public lastLogin: number
  ) {}
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpClientService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAccounts() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Account[]>('http://localhost:9898/api/v1/accountmanage/accounts');
  }

  public deleteAccount(account) {
    return this.httpClient.delete<User>(
      'http://localhost:9898/api/v1/accountmanage/account' + '/' + account.accountId
    );
  }

  public createAccount(account) {
    return this.httpClient.post<Account>(
      'http://localhost:9898/api/v1/accountmanage/account',
      account
    );
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.httpClient.get<User[]>('http://localhost:9898/api/v1/usermanage/users');
  }

  public deleteUser(user) {
    return this.httpClient.delete<User>(
      'http://localhost:9898/api/v1/usermanage/user' + '/' + user.userId
    );
  }

  public createUser(user) {
    return this.httpClient.post<User>(
      'http://localhost:9898/api/v1/usermanage/user',
      user
    );
  }
}
```

**UserComponet.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientService, User, Account } from "../service/httpclient.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-user",
  templateUrl: "./user.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./user.component.less"]
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["userId", "accountId", "userName", "emailAddress", "password", "enabled", "lastLogin", "delete"];

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClientService
      .getUsers()
      .subscribe(response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response));
  }

  handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
    this.users = response;
  }

  deleteUser(user: User): void {
    this.httpClientService.deleteUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      this.users = this.users.filter(u => u !== user);
    });
  }
}
```

**AccountComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientService, Account } from "../service/httpclient.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-account",
  templateUrl: "./account.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./account.component.less"]
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  accounts: Account[];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ["accountId", "accountName", "company", "address", "emailAddress", "dicomId", "enabled", "delete"];

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClientService
      .getAccounts()
      .subscribe(response => this.handleSuccessfulResponse(response));
  }

  handleSuccessfulResponse(response) {
    this.accounts = response;
  }

  deleteAccount(account: Account): void {
    this.httpClientService.deleteAccount(account).subscribe(data => {
      this.accounts = this.accounts.filter(u => u !== account);
    });
  }
}
```

**AddAccountComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientService, Account } from "../service/httpclient.service";
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: "app-add-account",
  templateUrl: "./add-account.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./add-account.component.less"]
})
export class AddAccountComponent implements OnInit {
  account: Account = new Account("","","","","","",0);

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService,
              private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  createAccount(): void {
    console.debug(this.account);
    this.httpClientService.createAccount(this.account).subscribe(data => {
      alert("Account created successfully.");
      this.router.navigate([''])
    });
  }
}
```

**AddUserComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientService, User, Account} from '../service/httpclient.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-user',
  templateUrl: './add-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user.component.less']
})
export class AddUserComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User = new User(null, null,
    null, "","",0,0);

  constructor(private httpClientService: HttpClientService,
              private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  createUser(): void {
    console.debug(this.user);
    this.httpClientService.createUser(this.user).subscribe(data => {
      alert('User created successfully.');
      this.router.navigate(['']);
    });
  }
}
```

Algunas preguntas similares que he podido encontrar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50918156/angular-5-select-all-users-with-related-role-onetomany-relationship
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33603168/angularjs-spring-jpa-repository-many-to-one-field-is-not-saving

Alguien por favor que esté al tanto de este lenguaje, en qué puedo mejorar en este escenario? Muchas gracias! :)

Pregunta en inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63483540/angular-example-many-to-one-and-one-to-many

Comment: Tengo la misma duda que en el sitio en ingles, cual es la pregunta? y sobre que? trata de ser mas claro cuando pones un monton de codigo, y explicar que problema tenes en particular.

Comment: Antes de empezar con el frontend, creo que debes probar bien tus puntos de api(puedes usar Postman) para que verifiques la información que retorna es la que necesitas en si creo que tu problema está más en spring antes que en angular. Agrega la version de Angular y la Java que estas usando por favor.

Comment: @all Muchas gracias por sus comentarios, caballeros. El problema con el que me he encontrado es diferenciar una clase de una interfaz en Angular, más bien. Cuándo tengo que utilizar una y cuando otra, por favor? La versión de Angular es la 8, Java 8 y Spring Boot 2.2.8

Comment: Y de  NodeJS, en versión 12.8.3. Sería compatible con Angular 8, o hay que cambiarlo a otra más estable?